# jQuery - How do I select div inside same table cell?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select a div that is inside the same tr as the href link.  I have several other divs in other table rows that share the same class.  I can't use parent(); or find();, can I?

```
<tr><td>
<a href="#" class="downloadTracksShow">Download Tracks</a><div class="downloadTracksDiv" style="display:none;">

<a href="downloads/mike/166320669010secreason.wav">Main Mix Track</a><br>
<a href="downloads/mike/94964secreason.wav">Bass</a><br></td></tr>
</div>


 $('.downloadTracksShow').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var tracksDiv = $(this).find(".downloadTracksDiv");
     $(tracksDiv).slideToggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.downloadTracksShow').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
 $('.downloadTracksShow').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).siblings("div.downloadTracksDiv").slideToggle();
 });
```